# How to use provider package to reload a widget tree of a stateless class

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

here is the logic, to get the data from the internet , when loading is not complete show a `progressbar` widget and when the loading is complete show the complete widget tree with text fields, pictures etc

firstly in the `mainscreen` i check if the data is downloaded form firebase

```
Future<void> getCurrentDriverInfo() async {
    // doublenotification++;
    currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    await driversRef
        .child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid)
        .once()
        .then((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
      if (databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null) {
        driversInformation = Drivers.fromSnapshot(databaseEvent.snapshot);
      }
    });
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Driver detail downloaded")));
    Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).getDriverDetailsDownload(true);
  }
```

This is the provider class

```
class AppData extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool driverDetaildownloaded = false;
  void getDriverDetailsDownload(bool driverDetaildownload) {
    driverDetaildownloaded = driverDetaildownload;
    print("Driverdownload" + driverDetaildownload.toString());
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Now inthis cass i want to check if the data is not downloaded then show just the progress bar and when the data is downloaded close the progress bar and show the widget tree

```
class ProfileTabPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
                .driverDetaildownloaded
            ? Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                 
                  Text(
                    driversInformation!.name!,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 65.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Signatra',
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              )
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However the `CircularProgressIndicator()` doesn't close and load the widgets. whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your UI: you have to set listen true,

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: true)
                .driverDetaildownloaded
        .....
```

another option: use Consumer

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: Consumer<AppData>(
     builder:(context,state,child) {
    return state.isDownloaded  
        ? your widget
        : CircularProgressIndicator(); 
    }
    )
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work, before downloading i can't set this to true as it gives a null error `Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).getDriverDetailsDownload(true);` This is why I am using `progressbar` .  to wait for data to download from firebase . then set the boolean to true, when i set it to true the progress bar will close and show widgets instead

Comment: updated my ansewer. I was thinking that , isdownloaded is a loading state. 

actually, you have to listen to the changes , to update your UI

Comment: believe it or not, i just wrote the same code a few minutes ago.

Comment: However, i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProfileTabPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Consumer<AppData>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => value.driverDetaildownloaded == true
            ? Column(  )
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```